# UPDATE id table on the columns with the same name

Tags: postgresql, update, table

I may be a newbie question but I don't know how to resolve this. I have a table like:

```
name | id       | value
A      1286487    1286333
B      1286489    1286403
C      1286495    1286455
C      1286496    1286375
D      1286503    1286341
B      1286506    1286343
```

And I want to update this table to make it like this:

```
name | id       | value
A      1286487    1286333
B      1286489    1286403
C      1286495    1286455
C      1286495    1286375
D      1286503    1286341
B      1286489    1286343
```

So rows with name B and C have the same id like the first row with this name. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fulfil the requirements, we have to first find the ID that we need - this can be found using the `min()` function, not surprisingly.  Then we do the update - the quickest to write is possibly the following:

```
UPDATE minupdate m 
   SET id = (SELECT min(id) 
               FROM minupdate
              WHERE name = m.name);
```

The backside of this is it can be *very* slow, if you have a bigger number of rows.  I have populated the table with some 50,000 random rows, using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO minupdate (name, id)
SELECT translate(substr(i::text, 1, 1), '1234567890', 'ABCDEFGHIJ'), 
       random() * 100000
FROM generate_series(1, 50000) t(i);
```

On my test box, without an index, this took looong minutes - I did not wait for it to produce an actual execution plan (using `EXPLAIN (ANAYLZE, BUFFERS)`, but cancelled and run it with `EXPLAIN` to see what's wrong:

```
 Update on minupdate m  (cost=0.00..136044281.50 rows=87720 width=12)
   ->  Seq Scan on minupdate m  (cost=0.00..136044281.50 rows=87720 width=12)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=1550.87..1550.88 rows=1 width=4)
                 ->  Seq Scan on minupdate  (cost=0.00..1526.50 rows=9747 width=4)
                       Filter: (name = m.name)
```

So I've added an index in (name, id) to get some faster results:

```
 Update on minupdate m  (cost=0.00..417486.00 rows=50000 width=15) (actual time=1771.008..1771.008 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=394845 read=653 dirtied=654
   ->  Seq Scan on minupdate m  (cost=0.00..417486.00 rows=50000 width=15) (actual time=0.062..1317.366 rows=50000 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=172641 read=192
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Result  (cost=8.31..8.32 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=1 loops=50000)
                 Buffers: shared hit=171655 read=192
                 InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                   ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=50000)
                         Buffers: shared hit=171655 read=192
                         ->  Index Only Scan using minupdate_name_id_idx on minupdate  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=50000)
                               Index Cond: ((name = m.name) AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                               Heap Fetches: 50000
                               Buffers: shared hit=171655 read=192
```

Now the problem is this: the inner part of the plan is executed 50,000 times - the number of rows to be updated.  In the index-less version, it would scan the whole table this may times - no wonder it would take very long.

But there is more to it.  Those 50,000 loops are ugly - let's find something nicer:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
UPDATE minupdate m 
   SET id = mins.id 
  FROM (SELECT name, min(id) AS id 
          FROM minupdate 
         GROUP BY name
       ) mins
WHERE m.name = mins.name;
```

This gives a more streamlined plan:

```
 Update on minupdate m  (cost=1861.76..4525.59 rows=91698 width=42) (actual time=995.845..995.845 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=241809 read=394 dirtied=843
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1861.76..4525.59 rows=91698 width=42) (actual time=218.866..542.437 rows=50000 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (m.name = mins.name)
         Buffers: shared hit=972 dirtied=427
         ->  Seq Scan on minupdate m  (cost=0.00..1402.98 rows=91698 width=8) (actual time=0.027..106.868 rows=50000 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=486 dirtied=1
         ->  Hash  (cost=1861.65..1861.65 rows=9 width=36) (actual time=218.816..218.816 rows=9 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
               Buffers: shared hit=486 dirtied=426
               ->  Subquery Scan on mins  (cost=1861.47..1861.65 rows=9 width=36) (actual time=218.738..218.790 rows=9 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=486 dirtied=426
                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1861.47..1861.56 rows=9 width=6) (actual time=218.722..218.740 rows=9 loops=1)
                           Group Key: minupdate.name
                           Buffers: shared hit=486 dirtied=426
                           ->  Seq Scan on minupdate  (cost=0.00..1402.98 rows=91698 width=6) (actual time=0.007..111.580 rows=50000 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=486 dirtied=426
 Planning time: 0.164 ms
 Execution time: 995.908 ms
```

There are now two sequential scan nodes there (somewhat surprisingly), but both are executed only once (`loops=1`).

What I've done here is removing a correlated subquery, replacing it by a temporary view (the query after `FROM`), joining it to the table to be updated.  This approach often gives far better plans than the easy way.  On big tables the performance difference can be quite significant.

Comment: One more thing: Avoid empty updates, add `AND m.id <> mins.id`. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860. And the index only pays for *many* duplicate names, else the added cost of updating the index will outweigh the benefit. (Leaving aside that duplicate `(id, name)` indicates problems in the original relational design.)